# How do we know how many prime knots there are for a specific number of crossings?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

For instance, on wikipedia it says there are 7 prime knots with 7 crossings. How do we know there isn't an 8th prime knot knot with 7 crossings that we haven't yet discovered?

Comment: There are only finitely many knot diagrams with $\leq 7$ crossings, so you can definitely list them all. The hard part is figuring out which are different knots. The Jones Polynomial is good at this, as is hyperbolic volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the only way is to enumerate over all possible diagrams up to the desired number of crossings and then do lots of hard work to eliminate the non-prime knots and remove all duplicates.

For 7 crossings you can probably do this easily by hand with a little patience. For more crossings a computer is desirable.

In fact, 7 crossings should be straightforward as every knot with 7 or fewer crossings is alternating, and its easy to check when alternating diagrams are the same, since the only isotopies between alternating diagrams you need to consider are flypes.

Thistlewaite, Hoste and Weeks are responsible for compiling knot tables for relatively large crossing numbers (up to 18 crossings now, I think). There is a nice overview of the menagerie of techniques they use here (Warning: ~3mb pdf):

http://pzacad.pitzer.edu/~jhoste/HosteWebPages/downloads/HTW.pdf

Comment: Thanks; I guess I was hoping for something a little more elegant than to just a brute force of how many prime knots there are for a given number of crossings.

Comment: @Kainui: You are hopeing for something impossible. Just for comparizon: Suppose you want to know how many prime numbers which are $\le 765$ are there. Is there an "elegant" way to do it?

Comment: Well prime numbers and prime knots aren't exactly the same thing. Just because they share the word "prime" doesn't really mean to me that there's some kind of correspondence between the two. There are only so many ways a knot can come to a certain crossing, I guess I supposed that there was some way to find something with perhaps a factorial in it or something in combinatorics or graph theory, since I know little about these.